# Centered fluid image with fixed aspect ratio and cropping - 2 overlayed divs

Tags: html, css, overlay, fluid-layout, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to use CSS only and no JavaScript, although that would not be a problem.

Requirements:
A horizontally centered image with a fixed aspect ratio (3:2). The image itself does not have a 3:2 aspect ratio, it's taller, so the bottom should be cropped. The image should be fluid, always scaling with the window, both in portrait and landscape orientations. It has a maximum width and height, so as to always be visible on screen.

I have managed to do all this, although it doesn't seem an elegant solution: it needs a transparent png to force the aspect ratio, and uses `background-image` to show the image itself. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/fseixas/u4e4xx1f

Now I need to have another div overlayed on top of this one, and I'm not able to do it. Any help?

(also, if you can provide a more elegant solution to the image problem, please do!)

Thanks,
fseixas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've altered your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4e4xx1f/16/) so that no image is needed. I've changed almost all the code, but what I've basically done, is add a container that will always have the perfect width of `max-width: calc(100vw - 60px)` and a width of `calc(150vh - 180px)` (1.5 times what the max-height should be and accounting for the header, footer and the margins).

Then I gave `#imagem` a padding-bottom of `calc(100% / 1.5)`, meaning that it will get exactly the same height as width, but divided by 1.5 (resulting in a ratio of `2:3`.

Hope this solved your problem

Comment: That's a nice solution. However, the image is not scalling correctly since it requires scrolling.

Edit: I fixed it with `width: calc(150vh - 120px)` (120px = 80*1.5) http://jsfiddle.net/fseixas/u4e4xx1f/15/

Comment: Oh the fix shouldn't be `width: calc(150vh - 120px)`, but `width: calc(150vh - 180px)`. I'll alter my answer

Comment: It's 120px because I need the `bottom` div to be outside the viewing area. By the way, in case this is useful to someone, here's the solution you provided but using an `<img>` tag and `object-fit` instead of `background-image`: http://jsfiddle.net/fseixas/u4e4xx1f/19